# Can't select tape printer

Tags: python-3.x, dymo

I try to automation printing labels en tapes. I can already print my labels. 
But when I try to select the tape printer it just prints een empty label instead of een empty tape. Any suggestions?

I got all the printers listed:

DYMO LabelWriter 450 DUO Tape =>DYMO LabelWriter 450 DUO Tape,DYMO LabelWriter 450 DUO Tape (this does not work)

DYMO LabelWriter 450 DUO Label => DYMO LabelWriter 450 DUO Label,DYMO LabelWriter 450 DUO Label (this work)

```
import sys
from os import path
from win32com.client import Dispatch

curdir = None
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # frozen
    curdir = path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    # unfrozen
    curdir = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))

mylabel = path.join(curdir,'Dossier.label')  #is file for tape

labelCom = Dispatch('Dymo.DymoAddIn')
labelText = Dispatch('Dymo.DymoLabels')
isOpen = labelCom.Open(mylabel)
selectPrinter = 'DYMO LabelWriter 450 DUO Tape' #DYMO LabelWriter 450 DUO Label then it prints empty label 
labelCom.SelectPrinter(selectPrinter)

labelCom.StartPrintJob()
labelCom.Print(1,False)
labelCom.EndPrintJob()
```

I expected to print een empty tape instead of een empty label.
Any idea how i can get the right printer?

Comment: have you read https://github.com/matteomattei/PyDymoLabel/blob/master/PyDymoLabel.py and https://gist.github.com/pawpro/4f195119670d4a5a574183765fe394ef and https://github.com/euphy/dymo-kanban-labels/blob/master/dymo_kanban_labels/lib/dymo.py

Comment: Yes I did, that works for the labels, i made already a program for that and that works. I want to use the tapwriter in the labelwriter 450 duo, but i can't find anything for it.